# Stripe - Create a Source for a Credit Card using only Stripe API

Tags: stripe-payments, react-native-stripe-api

I'm trying to register a user payment info by directly using `fetch` to Stripe's API (since it's a React Native app, I can't use Stripe Elements). It follows the usual concept: a user registers his credit card, which is then associated to his account so he can make payments in the app.

I tried to approach this problem by creating a credit card token with the info that the user provides on signup, but I've realized that that token is only worth for one payment, or for associating to a customer.

Meanwhile I saw that Sources are maybe what I need in my app, since we can get back to it and charge it multiple times. However, from what I see [in the API docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/sources/create) there's no reference to the credit card info when creating the source.

What do I need to create to be able to do this (registering a card to be used several times) only through the API?

Comment: I don't have experience with native development, but you probable should look into Stripe Customers API. BTW, qoute from Sources doc:


token


optional


An optional token used to create the source. When passed, token properties will override source parameters.

Comment: Yes, you're right! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating a token previously, you can then use it as an argument to the creation of the source. Then, the token properties will override source parameters. Thanks to @Evgenii Malikov for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a token of your card previously. For that, you can use [tipsi-stripe](https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe) package.
Perfect package if you want to implement credit card, apple / google pay.